# Add New Row at Middle of Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want to add new row at middle of the gridview. How to achieve this.

The Gridview bind by DataTable. In DataBound Event I want to add new row in particular row, using row index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert a row at specific position use the API of your binding source. For example if the grid is bound to a DataTable use the following code:

```
DataRow row = table.NewRow();
table.Rows.InsertAt(row, 5);
```

[DataGridView.Rows Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows.aspx)